# should I escape code stored in mysql db or use placeholders?

Tags: mysql, perl

I just found out about placeholders in DBI https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values and it seems to be handling various codes pretty well.
Should I be forcing escape regardless? Are there any scenarios where the placeholders would fail based on the input?

Answer (score 4):

If you escape them and then use bound placeholders, they will end up double escaped, which is not what you want. Just use placeholders. (I frequently use them even when the input is trusted, because it looks cleaner.)

There is rarely a reason to use escaping instead of placeholders. An example would be dynamically generating and manipulating a query as an SQL string, but you really shouldn't do that anyway (there are plenty of libraries on CPAN for generating SQL).

The only example that I know of in which a placeholder would fail based on input that would not fail with string interpretation would be when you are interpolating column names from a string, LIMIT clauses, or some such (but again, that is dynamic generating SQL like I mentioned above.)

Placeholders >> manual escaping

Comment: DBI also tells you about missing params if you are using placeholders, which can help locate problems. One more thing: if you want DBI to escape strings for an `IN ('foo', 'bar')` block, you cannot use placeholders. Use `join ',', map $dbh->quote($_), qw(foo bar)` instead.

Comment: Good point about debugging, but as for your second point, `IN (?, ?, ...)` works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: It does, but only if you know the number of values. If you've got i.e. a list of names, product ids or whatever, and that list changes depending on some other parameter, you'll need to make that on the fly. In that case, it's simpler and clearer to use `quote` directly then to check how many `?` you need. You can also combine both methods. I think it does no harm adding the quoted params this way if it is necessary.